# Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet

Tags: apt, 18.04, docker

I am using Ansible to install the Nginx packages on my Slave1 server from Master server (Note- both Master & Slave server's are having Ubuntu 18.04 and i am running these inside Docker containers), but everytime i am running the Ansible command to do this, getting below error. I am stuck here, what is the solution for this. Please heklp me in debugging this issue.

```
root@afb19093484e:/# ansible Slave1 -m apt -a "name=nginx state=present"


172.17.0.3 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "cmd": "apt-get update", 
    "msg": "E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 3d 21h 33min 13s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.\nE: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 3d 23h 23min 36s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.", 
    "rc": 100, 
    "stderr": "E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 3d 21h 33min 13s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.\nE: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 3d 23h 23min 36s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.\n", 
    "stderr_lines": [
        "E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 3d 21h 33min 13s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.", 
    ],
```

Comment: Check the time on your computer system (use the command `date` for this).

Comment: make sure time and date in slave1 synced

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys. It worked for me :) there was time difference on both server's. Synced the time and things worked.

Comment: @PankajNavneet if HairyNetworkAdmin's answer below was the correct solution, can you please mark it accepted? This helps folks with the same problem find answers easier :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sudo apt update error: "Release file is not yet valid"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096930/sudo-apt-update-error-release-file-is-not-yet-valid)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that the system clock is set to UTC, and is within a few minutes of UTC.